# C: How is binary-mode versus text-mode implemented for `fopen`?

Tags: c, file-io, cross-platform, libc

As a learning exercise, I am attempting to write a platform layer in C for Windows and GNU/Linux operating systems.

I am currently interested in implementing a function which opens a file on the host platform in a provided mode, similar to `fopen` from `<stdio.h>`. I know there is the Windows API function `CreateFile` from `<fileapi.h>`, and the GNU function `open` from `<fcntl.h>`; I am thinking I can use these to open a file from disk for reading or writing. However, `fopen` also provides a mode choice between opening a file in binary-mode versus text-mode. I do not entirely understand how the difference between these works under the hood; how would I go about implementing this functionality in my version?

Comment: On posix/linux/*BSD, there is _no_ difference. It is merely how `fgets` interprets a line of text. On linux, the line terminator is `\n` (newline/0x0A). On windows, the line terminator is `\r\n` (crlf, cr/newline, 0x0D/0x0A). If you pass `b` (for binary) to `fopen`, it adds `O_BINARY` to the flags given to [the underlying] `open` call (or win32 equiv.). Under linux, the app layer (e.g. `fgets`) handles the line terminator. I can't remember the exact mechanism, but Windows handles this in the kernel. It's low level read will work differently depending upon the mode.

Comment: Under windows, with `O_BINARY`, you'll see `\r\n`. Without it (i.e. `O_TEXT`), the `\r\n` is massaged to `\n` on the fly. Reiterating, on linux et. al. `b` and `O_BINARY` are no-ops, provided for win32 compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do not entirely understand how the difference between these works under the hood;

When code uses `"b"` to open a file, there is *no* translation.  Whatever is in the file is what is read.  Whatever is written to the file is written.

When code does not use `"b"` to open a file, there is a potential translation.  An outgoing `"\n"` may get translated into `"\r\n"`, `"\r"`, `"\n"` or something else.  The last write may append a <kbd>Ctrl z</kbd> or not.  The beginning of the file may include a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).  Other translations are possible.  Reading of such files may consume the above mentioned and present the code with less info.  There are many *implementation specific* aspects to reading and writing such a *text file*.

When reading/writing a *text* file, do not use `"b"`.  Otherwise do not open with a `"b"`.

---

> how would I go about implementing this functionality in my version?

If reading a *text* file, do not use `"b"`, otherwise use `"b"`.

Answer (score 1):

On Microsoft Windows, text files usually use the characters `\r\n` (carriage-return followed by line-feed) as line endings. When reading from files opened in text mode, the `\r\n` line endings get translated to `\n`, so that it appears to the application that the line endings consisted of `\n` instead of `\r\n`. Also, when writing to files in text mode, `\n` line endings get translated to `\r\n`. These translations do not happen in binary mode. Also, the byte value `0x1A` is interpreted as the end of the file in text mode, but not in binary mode.

However, on GNU/Linux (and all other POSIX platforms), there is no difference between text mode and binary mode. In both modes, no translation takes place. This is because on that platform, the line endings of text files natively only consist of `\n`, so no translation is required.

Comment: Actually, "line endings" presumes a lot. It is the two byte sequence CRLF translated to LF when reading, and LF translated to CRLF when writing... The poor sap who neglected specifying "b" when opening a file (binary data or text) can look forward to working overtime to find'n'fix the problem that may appear as "corrupted data".

Comment: In the original Mac OS (when it was named "System"), and some other obscure ones like OS/9, the end of line is \r.